# How to trigger a function of Xcode extension from the UI of the containing app?

Tags: xcode, xpc, xcode-extension

I am trying to trigger a function in my Xcode extension from the UI of the containing app and ultimately trigger functions in the containing app from the code in the extension.

According to this tutorial, it should work using XPC Service https://kowei-chen.medium.com/xcode-extension-1-5-starting-guide-519a95bdc865 (unfortunately this tutorial ends after chapter 1)

I have successfully set up the extension and an XPC Service which I can call but I just don’t get how this XPC Service should call a function from the Extension.

Does anybody know how to implement this? Thanks!